# Ledger Report Logic in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2014

i have a Stored Procedure  called "Patient Ledger Report" where i need to show the day to day transaction details and balance amount of the patients.i was providing you one sampled data from below code how the data was inserting into my temporary table in my sp.

```
create table #Patient_ledger (PATIENT_NAME varchar(250),PATIENT_NBR bigint,BILLNO varchar(250),BILLAMOUNT bigint,
PAID_AMOUNT bigint)

Insert into #Patient_ledger (Patient_name ,Patient_nbr ,billno ,billamount ,
paid_amount )

select 'ABC',1,'DUE_BILL_ABC_1',100,50
union all
select 'ABC',1,'DUE_BILL_ABC_2',160,90
UNION ALL
select 'ABC',1,'DEPOSIT_BILL_ABC',0,60
UNION ALL
select 'XYZ',2,'DEPOSIT_BILL_XYZ',0,70
UNION ALL
select 'XYZ',2,'DUE_BILL_XYZ_1',100,30

SELECT * FROM #Patient_ledger

Drop table #Patient_ledger
```

How i want to show the data in my report.

```
 PATIENT_NUMBER   BILLNO         BILLAMOUNT  PAID_AMOUNT  BALANCE

    1          DUE_BILL_ABC_1      100         50            50  --(100-50)     
    1          DUE_BILL_ABC_2      160         90            120  --(160-90 +50(Here 50 is prev balance amount of same patient))
    1          DEPOSIT_BILL_ABC     0          40            80 ---( 120-40=80)
    2          DEPOSIT_BILL_XYZ     0          70            0        
    2          DUE_BILL_XYZ_1      100         30            0  --Here Balance is zero because  patient has deposited some      
                                                                 --amount before bill (70-100+30=0)      

Note: Balance amount should deduct when deposits are paid by that particual patient.
```

Comment: why 4th row balance is 0 ? It should be 80-70=10

Comment: is there a date to order these records or an identity?

Comment: @KumarHarsh possibly because it's a different patient?

Comment: why have you tagged 3 versions of sql-server?

Comment: you need to have  a column like bill date to order by, do you have any such column

Comment: yes you need there column that can show us order, for example identity id, datetime or so...

Comment: @Ashu i have gave you the just sample data but in actual data there are some identity columns and date columns to order by the data

Comment: @KumarHarsh in the fourth column balance amount is zero because patient was deposited some amount 70 (observer third column) before he has done the bill.

Comment: @Matej In the actual sp data there are some identity columns and date columns from different tables to order by the data

Comment: then try to use my solution bit lower :)

Comment: @Matej it works as exactly what i need -:)

Comment: @Buddi thanks for your code.its also working

Comment: @Mahesh.K Thank you and accept any of the answers below which met your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried like below it may help you

```
SELECT Patient_nbr,
       billno,
       billamount,
       PAID_AMOUNT,
       CASE
         WHEN RNO > 1 THEN Sum(billamount - PAID_AMOUNT)
                             OVER(
                               PARTITION BY Patient_nbr
                               ORDER BY RNO)
         ELSE Iif(( billamount - PAID_AMOUNT ) < 0, 0, billamount - PAID_AMOUNT)
       END
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Row_number()
                 OVER(
                   PARTITION BY Patient_nbr
                   ORDER BY Patient_nbr) AS RNO
        FROM   #Patient_ledger) A
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to put there also order discriminator, it could seems like this: (I consider also fact that there can be more DUE/DEPOSITS for one PATIENT_NBR)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Patient_ledger') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Patient_ledger
    CREATE TABLE #Patient_ledger 
    (ID INT IDENTITY, 
     PATIENT_NAME varchar(250),
     PATIENT_NBR bigint,
     BILLNO varchar(250),
     BILLAMOUNT bigint,
     PAID_AMOUNT bigint)

Insert into #Patient_ledger (PATIENT_NAME ,PATIENT_NBR ,BILLNO ,BILLAMOUNT ,
PAID_AMOUNT )

select 'ABC',1,'DUE_BILL_ABC_1',100,50
union all
select 'ABC',1,'DUE_BILL_ABC_2',160,90
UNION ALL
select 'ABC',1,'DEPOSIT_BILL_ABC',0,40
UNION ALL
select 'XYZ',2,'DEPOSIT_BILL_XYZ',0,70
UNION ALL
select 'XYZ',2,'DUE_BILL_XYZ_1',100,30


;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT PATIENT_NBR, 
       BILLNO,
       PAID_AMOUNT,
       BILLAMOUNT,
       BILLAMOUNT-PAID_AMOUNT AS BALANCE, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PATIENT_NBR ORDER BY ID) AS RN
FROM #Patient_ledger)

SELECT a.PATIENT_NBR,
       a.BILLNO,
       a.BILLAMOUNT,
       a.PAID_AMOUNT,
       CASE WHEN ISNULL(LAG(a.BALANCE + ISNULL(x.ADDS,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY a.PATIENT_NBR ORDER BY a.RN),0) + a.BILLAMOUNT - a.PAID_AMOUNT < 0 
            THEN 0
            ELSE a.BALANCE + ISNULL(x.ADDS,0)
       END AS FINAL_BALANCE

FROM CTE a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(BALANCE) AS ADDS 
                FROM CTE f 
                    WHERE f.PATIENT_NBR = a.PATIENT_NBR AND f.RN < a.RN) x
```

Comment: i want the logic without using the Lag function.because our clients servers are 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and tell me if it work with other sample data too.

```
create table #Patient_ledger (PATIENT_NAME varchar(250),PATIENT_NBR bigint
,BILLNO varchar(250),BILLAMOUNT bigint,PAID_AMOUNT bigint)

Insert into #Patient_ledger (Patient_name ,Patient_nbr ,billno 
,billamount ,paid_amount )

select 'ABC',1,'DUE_BILL_ABC_1',100,50
union all
select 'ABC',1,'DUE_BILL_ABC_2',160,90
UNION ALL
select 'ABC',1,'DEPOSIT_BILL_ABC',0,40
UNION ALL
select 'XYZ',2,'DEPOSIT_BILL_XYZ',0,70
UNION ALL
select 'XYZ',2,'DUE_BILL_XYZ_1',100,30


SELECT PATIENT_NBR PATIENT_NUMBER
    ,BILLNO
    ,BILLAMOUNT
    ,PAID_AMOUNT
    ,CASE 
        WHEN billamount = 0
            AND lag((BILLAMOUNT - PAID_AMOUNT), 1, 0) OVER (
                PARTITION BY PATIENT_NBR ORDER BY PATIENT_NBR
                ) = 0
            THEN 0
        ELSE SUM((BILLAMOUNT - PAID_AMOUNT)) OVER (
                PARTITION BY PATIENT_NBR ORDER BY PATIENT_NBR ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                )
        END Balance
FROM #Patient_ledger

Drop table #Patient_ledger
```

Comment: i want the logic without using the Lag function.because our clients servers are 2008.