# Compute running balance for loan accounts in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

These tables are in SQL Server. I need to get the outstanding balance of the account per transaction based on the amount paid by the customer. The `PAYMENT` table contains payments of the customer in every transaction. The `Account` table contains the account details and total loan amount of the client.

**Payment**:

```
    +--------------+------------+----------+
    | payment_date | account_no |  amount  |
    +--------------+------------+----------+
    | 2017-08-10   |  123456789 |   5000   |
    | 2017-08-15   |  987654321 |   3000   |
    | 2017-09-15   |  987654321 |   3000   |
    | 2017-10-11   |  123456789 |   4000   |
    | 2017-10-16   |  987654321 |   3500   |
    | 2017-11-10   |  123456789 |   3000   |
    | 2017-11-15   |  987654321 |   2500   |
    +--------------+------------+----------+
```

**Account**:

```
    +--------------+-------------+---------------+
    | account_no   | accountname |  loan_amount  |
    +--------------+-------------+---------------+
    |  123456789   |     John    |   15000       |
    |  987654321   |     Jane    |   20000       |
    +--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

From these table, I should be able to display the following data:

**Customer ledger**:

```
    +--------------+------------+----------+----------------------+
    | payment_date | account_no |  amount  | outstanding_balance  |
    +--------------+------------+----------+----------------------+
    | 2017-08-10   |  123456789 |   5000   |        10000         |
    | 2017-10-11   |  123456789 |   4000   |         6000         |
    | 2017-11-10   |  123456789 |   3000   |         3000         |
    | 2017-08-15   |  987654321 |   3000   |        17000         |
    | 2017-09-15   |  987654321 |   3000   |        14000         |
    | 2017-10-16   |  987654321 |   3500   |        11500         |
    | 2017-11-15   |  987654321 |   2500   |         9000         |
    +--------------+------------+----------+----------------------+
```

Comment: what have you tried? have you done any Research online?

Comment: Check this link .this may help you a lot [Refer this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236663/ledger-report-logic-in-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT row we can get the result

```
SELECT     p.payment_date , 
           a.account_no , 
           p.amount , 
           outstanding_balance=a.loan_amount-sum( p.amount)OVER( 
                                                PARTITION BY a.account_no ORDER BY a.account_no rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT row)
FROM       @payment p 
INNER JOIN @account a 
ON         p.account_no=a.account_no
```

Result

```
payment_date    account_no  amount  outstanding_balance
--------------------------------------------------------
2017-08-10      123456789   5000    10000
2017-10-11      123456789   4000    6000
2017-11-10      123456789   3000    3000
2017-11-15      987654321   2500    17500
2017-10-16      987654321   3500    14000
2017-08-15      987654321   3000    11000
2017-09-15      987654321   3000    8000
```

Answer (score 0):

If 2012+, you an use the window function **sum() over** in concert with a a simple join.

**Example**

```
Select P.*
      ,outstanding = A.loan_amount - sum(P.amount) over (Partition By P.account_no Order By P.payment_date)
 From  Payment P
 Join  Account A on A.account_no=P.account_no
```

**Returns**

[image]